# GC and memory limit issues with R

Tags: memory, r, garbage-collection

I am using R on some relatively big data and am hitting some memory issues.  This is on Linux.  I have significantly less data than the available memory on the system so it's an issue of managing transient allocation.

When I run gc(), I get the following listing

```
           used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   2147186  114.7    3215540  171.8   2945794  157.4
Vcells 251427223 1918.3  592488509 4520.4 592482377 4520.3
```

yet R appears to have 4gb allocated in resident memory and 2gb in swap.  I'm assuming this is OS-allocated memory that R's memory management system will allocate and GC as needed.  However, lets say that I don't want to let R OS-allocate more than 4gb, to prevent swap thrashing.  I could always ulimit, but then it would just crash instead of working within the reduced space and GCing more often.  Is there a way to specify an arbitrary maximum for the gc trigger and make sure that R never os-allocates more?  Or is there something else I could do to manage memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: no.  I found that you simply cannot micromanage memory management and `gc()`.

On the other hand, you could try to keep your data in memory, but 'outside' of R. The [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) makes that fairly easy.  Of course, using a 64bit version of R and ample ram may make the problem go away too.

Comment: `bigmemory` keeps things on disk, doesn't it?

Comment: No, you may be thinking of `ff` does.

Comment: Ok, good to clear that up.  The documentation says that `bigmemory` "may use memory-mapped files".  Not sure when or how it relates.  I never looked into the bigmemory internals, but it looks like it uses Boost.Interprocess.

Comment: If you instruct it too, it can map memory to files. By default it uses just ram.  And hey, Jay and Mike are locals at your RUG, so how come I have to explain this? ;-)

Comment: I know...and Jay *did* explain it, but I'm dense.